# recursive function working for arrays but not vectors c++

Tags: c++, recursion, vector, stdvector

Why does this code work for arrays but not vectors? When I replace the data type to array, it works. I thought both were mutable.
For reference, the program is supposed to return 1 4 10 14 22, or the accumulated value so far for each index.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void accum(vector<int> v, int len)
{
    if (len == 1){
        return;
    }
    accum(v, len-1);
    v[len-1] += v[len-2];
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v = {1, 3, 6, 4, 8};
    accum(v, 5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code works when you implement the function with an array instead of a vector. I have no idea why, or how to make it also work with arrays.

Comment: What have your text-books, tutorials or teachers said about passing arguments by *reference*?

Comment: Because you're passing it by value. Vectors are mutable, but you're mutating a different vector. When you're passing an "array", you're actually passing a pointer.

Comment: Side note: What would occur on an *empty* vector??? Compare for `<= 1`, not `== 1` to catch this case.

Comment: By the way: Correct type for array sizes/length or size/length of vector contents is `size_t`, not `int`...

Comment: To explain what happens now when you pass the vector by value: A *copy* is made, and each function only modifies its local copy. It worked with C-style arrays because then you passed a pointer to the first element of the array, and no copying of the array itself happens.

Comment: Also, side note, `accum()` could be written better, to avoid the unnecessary subtractions.

Comment: @Aconcagua That really requires an `assert(len<=v.size())` because it's always an error to pass in an invalid parameter.

Comment: @Spencer No, it doesn't! If placed or not doesn't make the programme more correct, it only supports the *developer* in finding erroneous conditions that the programme *itself* produced, thus in finding programming errors (bugs). Note especially that `assert` isn't active any more in release builds (with `NDEBUG` being defined)! If the parameter can get invalid due to invalid user input (imagine the programme would allow to accumulate only a sub-range of the vector) you need to test it with regular `if` clauses!!!

Comment: @Spencer Now if we need such a test or not depends on how the function actually gets called. Counter example: Maybe later on `accum(std::vector<int>&, size_t)` gets private and is always called via a public helper `void accum(std::vector<int>& v) { accum v, v.size(); }` – and the parameter cannot get invalid any more (theoretically, at least – if id still did in practice then an `assert` would help to catch that)...

Comment: @Aconcagua _it's always an error to pass in an invalid parameter._,  Meaning that the failure of any such check inside the function should raise an exception.   Meaning you don't make this check if you can guarantee the argument is valid before calling the function.  Making a release build is an expression of that guarantee. So this is exactly what `assert` does.   If it's really critical (`push_that_red_button()`) you can make an analogue of `assert` that always makes the check regardless of build type.

Comment: @Aconcagua If the parameter can get invalid due to invalid user input you _definitely_ need to test it with regular if clauses, but you don't do it in a place (like inside this function) where there's no good recourse for invalid input -- you validate the user input _before_ calling the function.  This is a basic separation of concepts situation.

Comment: @Spencer Agree, for the recursion it would be the wrong place as needlessly being tested again and again with every recursive call. But one wouldn't solve this kind of problem recursively either – normally... Did not want to dig that deep into the discussion actually – just wanted to emphasise that `assert` – albeit being a useful and valuable tool, indeed, though sometimes overestimated – it's simply no *requirement*...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you used it -> call by value
solve -> call by reference

before

```
void accum(vector<int> v, int len) // call by value
```

after

```
void accum(vector<int> &v, int len) // call by reference
```

Answer (score 2):

Vectors in C++ are passed by value into a function unlike arrays.

That means when vectors are passed to a function, C++ creates a copy of it and then passes. Therefore, when the recursive runs, the original vector is not changed

`void accum(vector<int>& v, int len)`

and call the function as

```cpp
vector<int> v;
accum(v, v.size())
```